# External links from search engine - Redirect?

Tags: php, html, seo, hyperlink

I am making a site which is designed to contain a large amount of links to other sites, much like a search engine. I have seen two different approached with regards to linking to external sites.

1. Simply to link directly to the external content directly from the links on my own site
2. To redirect to the content via an internal link, such as www.site.com/r/myref123 -> www.internet.com/hello.php

Would anyone be able to tell me what the advantage is with each approach? I am stuck at a crossroads here and can't find much information on which approach I should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit opinion based, so I wouldn't be surprised if the question gets closed off, but I think that the second option is the better by FAR.

The reason being is that you are then able to track who clicks through to what. You are then also able to perform some fancy code that the user will never see - such as internally ranking sites that generate a lot of click-through traffic when presented in a list of choices.

Of course, lastly, and most importantly, if you are going to possibly throw in some links that generate some sort of income, you need to be able to track those clicks. If you simply present them and do nothing more, you will have no way to bill your advertisers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to track when, who, from where, etc are links clicked. If you put one of your pages in between the original page and the linked one, you will be able to do so.

In case you use the 1st version, whenever a click is done it will directly go to the referred page and you won't have any way to track it.

If you use the 2nd version, you will be able to track the clicks done by visitors through a script located in the `www.site.com/r/myref...`.